# I am fetching file names for certain user and group name. I want filename which are in different rows to be in same row

Tags: sql-server

I am fetching file names for certain user and group name. I want filename which are in different rows as in table to be in same row. kindly look into it
  Fetched & expected:
       My result is:
        2 group 2 file1 10
        2 group 2 file2 10

```
  I want is:
    2 group 2 file1 10 file2 10
```

My procedure:

```
   Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[DisplayDetails] 
            @User_Id int,
            @Group_Id int OUTPUT,
            @Group_Name varchar(255) OUTPUT,
            @No_of_flat_files int OUTPUT,
            @Filename varchar(255) OUTPUT,
            @No_of_records int OUTPUT


        AS
        BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

            select @Group_Id=Group_Id,
            @Group_Name=Group_Name,
            @No_of_flat_files=No_of_flat_files,@Filename=file_name,
            @No_of_records=No_of_records from INPUT_FILES_updated
            where file_sequence='1' and [User_Id]=@User_Id
            union 
            select @Group_Id=Group_Id,
            @Group_Name=Group_Name,
            @No_of_flat_files=No_of_flat_files,@Filename=file_name, 
            @No_of_records=No_of_records from INPUT_FILES_updated
            where file_sequence='2' and  [User_Id]=@User_Id
            union
             select @Group_Id=Group_Id,
            @Group_Name=Group_Name,
            @No_of_flat_files=No_of_flat_files,@Filename=file_name,
            @No_of_records=No_of_records from INPUT_FILES_updated
            where file_sequence='3' and  [User_Id]=@User_Id
            union
            select @Group_Id=Group_Id,
            @Group_Name=Group_Name,
            @No_of_flat_files=No_of_flat_files,@Filename=file_name,
            @No_of_records=No_of_records from INPUT_FILES_updated
            where file_sequence='4' and  [User_Id]=@User_Id



           RETURN  
        END





             Declare @Group_I int  ,@Group_Na varchar(50),@No_of_flat_fil int,
        @Filena varchar(255) ,  @No_of_reco int     

                Execute [dbo].[DisplayDetails] @User_Id=2, @Group_Id=@Group_I output,  @Group_Name=@Group_Na output,@No_of_flat_files=@No_of_flat_fil out,@Filename=@Filena out,@No_of_records=@No_of_reco

                SELECT @Group_I,@Group_Na ,@No_of_flat_fil, @Filena, @No_of_reco
```

Comment: Is this SQL server or MySql?

Comment: Cool - does your stored procedure even compile? Can you also post some sample data.

Comment: yes,,, I fetched two rows but I want that value in single row

Comment: Does your required result always have 5 (I can't actually tell from your example) columns or might there be many more columns? You want to do a crosstab. The SQL Server PIVOT key may help you but it requires a fixed known number of columns.

Comment: I have only 2 files int this table which I can fetch through union... 2 group  file1 10   , 2 group  file2 20.  but I want file with same group name "group" to come in same row as 2 group file1 10 file2 20

Comment: how can I use pivot on the basis of group id 2..to just show the file names in pivot sequence

Comment: @thakur Please generate sample content and provide desired output.

Comment: @AmitSukralia You are right: `Variable assignment is not allowed in a statement containing a top level UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.` I did not believe my eyes and had to try.

Comment: fortunately, it is working for me guys